# Delaying meeting invitations in Outlook 2010 - vba

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, calendar, meetings

I am trying to write a code to schedule a meeting invite and delay sending to participants at a later date/time automatically, i.e. delay sending a meeting invite

Below is the code but it is giving an error at the point where I want the invitation to be sent 30 minutes later.

Error line :

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("06:30:00"))

Will really appreciate help on this. Many thanks

```
Sub Book_meeting_room()


Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olApt As AppointmentItem

Set olApp = Outlook.Application                 'Creating Outlook Session
Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 'Creating an Appointment

With olApt

.MeetingStatus = olMeeting                  'olAppointmentItem with Meeting status olMeeting
                                            'becomes a OL Meeting Item.
.Subject = "Room 1"                         'Subject
.Start = #11/20/2017 8:30:00 AM#            'Enter Date + Time here.
.Duration = 240                             'In Minutes
.Location = "Office"                        'Location of the meeting.
.Recipients.Add ("Margaret")                'Recipient Name, Alias, or any other Attribute.
.BusyStatus = olFree
.ReminderSet = True
.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 20

End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("06:30:00"))          'defer 06hrs and 30mins.
olApt.Send                             'Sending Mail.
Set olApt = Nothing

MsgBox "Invite Sent", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message? The TIMEVALUE function returns a serial number of a time. I don't think this is what you want?

Comment: It is giving Debug error.. the macro works fine up until the Application.wait syntax
I am looking for to delay delivery of the meeting invite

Comment: While this question is different in some ways, it is also the same topic as your other question: https://superuser.com/questions/1260042/delaying-meeting-invitations-in-outlook-2010 There are a few possible ways to fix this situation: Use the Edit button on your previous question to substantially change it and delete this question. Mark an answer as accepted on the other question so it can be closed, or delete the other question entirely. What should not happen is for you to leave the older question either unaccepted or open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delaying meeting invitations in Outlook 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/1260042/delaying-meeting-invitations-in-outlook-2010)

Comment: I have deleted the previous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.Wait` doesn't work with outlook you can either use the `Doevent` function with a timer, or the `Sleep` function

Using `Doevent` is the best option because it will allow you to keep working after starting the macro, issue happens if you over use it:

```
Public Sub Pause(Seconds As Single)
Dim TimeEnd As Single
TimeEnd = Timer + Seconds
While Timer < TimeEnd
    DoEvents
Wend
End Sub
```

With sleep you need to declare the function and it will not allow you to work anymore until the message is sent. You declare it with:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

your code becomes as follow (you can also note the additional other issue that will be solved with `.Display` to make the program work)

```
Sub Book_meeting_room()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olApt As AppointmentItem

Set olApp = Outlook.Application                 'Creating Outlook Session
Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 'Creating an Appointment

With olApt

.MeetingStatus = olMeeting                  'olAppointmentItem with Meeting status olMeeting
                                            'becomes a OL Meeting Item.
.Subject = "Room 1"                         'Subject
.Start = #11/20/2017 8:30:00 AM#            'Enter Date + Time here.
.Duration = 240                             'In Minutes
.Location = "Office"                        'Location of the meeting.
.Recipients.Add ("Margaret")                'Recipient Name, Alias, or any other Attribute.
.BusyStatus = olFree
.ReminderSet = True
.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 20
.Display

End With

Pause (23400) 'defer 06hrs and 30mins.
'Sleep (23400) 'also defer 06hrs and 30mins eventually

olApt.Send                             'Sending Mail.
Set olApt = Nothing

MsgBox "Invite Sent", vbInformation

End Sub
```